# Missing Messages and Secure logs files on CentOS

Tags: centos, logs, rsyslog

I'm having troubles with CentOS release 6.4 (Final). I'm looking for log files in `/var/log/` and I'm obviously missing two files:

- `/var/logs/messages`
- `/var/log/secure`

I was checking if rsyslog is running (`service rsyslog status`) and it's *OK*. My rsyslog config file is called `/etc/rsyslog.conf`, folder `/etc/rsysconf.d/` is empty.

Can anyone shed some light on what's going on?

Comment: lsof | grep messages?

Comment: the result of `lsof | grep messages` is blank. No response. And I'm getting the same result for `lsof | grep secure`

Comment: [this discussion](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92522/how-to-tell-rsyslog-to-create-log-file-if-not-there) might be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check if have any rule for store in **/var/log/messages** or **/var/log/secure** in **/etc/rsyslog.conf** like

```
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none  /var/log/messages

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*   /var/log/secure
```

if does not have , add this line and restart your rsyslog service.

```
/etc/init.d/rsyslog restart
```

or

```
service rsyslog restart
```

Comment: I have there following lines: `# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none /var/log/messages# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.* /var/log/secure`

Answer (score 0):

the problem may that in RHEL7 (CentOS) and Fedora now use journald, which listens on /dev/log for incoming messages; rsyslog actually reads messages from the journal via its API by default but installed rsyslog needed. Try journalctl.